# Error: Cannot find module 'css-selector-tokenizer'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli

Recently, I've been having trouble getting started with the Vue-CLI. I would create a project using the `vue create [name of project]` command and yarn would successfully (or at least I think 'cause I get no errors) install the relevant modules. The problem arises when launching said project via the `yarn serve` script, during compilation. I get the `Error: Cannot find module 'css-selector-tokenizer'` error message, as noted in the title and illustrated below in the linked image. I'm working with Vue 3.0.4 and have already used it before for other projects without issues. Also, I have not changed anything on my machine that would impact the CLI's functioning, hence the rather bizarre situation. I did try to manually install the 'css-selector-tokenizer' module but to no avail. What gives?

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Try uninstalling dependencies, while removing `yarn-lock.json` and `package-lock.json`. Also, try to create a new empty project and check if issue persists. If it does, try to install `css-loader` manually, as mentioned library is a dependency for it.

Comment: @aBiscuit Tried this but was unsuccessful. Nevertheless, a yarn (npm for those using it) clean cache, deleting the node_modules folder followed by a fresh install of dependencies did the trick. Thanks!